# How can a create a template solution in VS 2019 where projects lie in folders?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've been following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-multi-project-templates?view=vs-2019) of creating a multi-project template. It was successful, even if I am using a newer version (3, not 2).

The thing is, that I would like to have some projects in some folders. So when I use/apply the template, I want to have certain projects in certain folders. I have attached two screenshots for a better understanding.

[image]

[image]

The .vstemplate file looks like this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Multi-Project Template Sample</Name>
    <Description>&lt;Hacuna matata;</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
        <ProjectCollection>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="ConsoleApp1">
                Part1\ConsoleApp1\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="Liviu">
                Part2\ClassLibrary1\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </ProjectCollection>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

I tried combinations like `ProjectName="Part1\ConsoleApp1"`, but I only got errors. I've been looking on the [template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/template-parameters?view=vs-2019), nothing promising there.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the projects and the folders is specified in the .SLN file. Every project and every folder has a Project entry like this:

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "SampleApplication.Services", "SampleApplication.Services\SampleApplication.Services.csproj", "{780D4A9C-AB47-4B3C-8402-8B2C85E9B904}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Services", "Services", "{6B99D4BE-213F-4F2F-88A1-E7C9933EF3C6}"
EndProject
```

(The latter "project" is the folder).

The first GUID on the line is the project type, the second is the unique identifier of the project.

At the end of the .SLN file, there should be a GlobalSection(NestedProjects)

```
GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {780D4A9C-AB47-4B3C-8402-8B2C85E9B904} = {6B99D4BE-213F-4F2F-88A1-E7C9933EF3C6}
EndGlobalSection
```

Every line defines the parent folder (which is also a project) for a project in the form:

```
{project GUID} = {folder GUID}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new folder to the solution using VS if you require a new folder.

[image]

You can add a new project to the folder then.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, however I was hoping to have the folders from the first place -without creating them manually.

Comment: It works that way in CSPROJ files (when using .NET Core, .NET Standard or .NET Framework using the new file format). Folders are automatically recognized. In solutions, it is not like that.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying some other things in the meantime regarding this. Are you saying that crating a solution template that automatically creates olders is not possible?

Comment: @LiviuSosu No. It is not about creating. It is about recognizing folders automatically. Does work in projects. Does not work in solutions.